# in SP19 classic Is there a way to display missing items

Tags: list, 2019, classic-experience

I have 3 lists, first is a list of possible items, second is a list of people and the third is list of which people have what items. I am trying to find a way to display which items people do not have. Example below

**People**

1. Adam
2. Bob
3. Carl

**Items**

1. Apple
2. Rice
3. Water

Paired list

1. Adam has Apple
2. Adam has Water
3. Bob has Apple
4. Bob has Rice
5. Carl has Water

I am trying to reverse the paired list to what items people do not have.
IE

1. Adam does not have Rice
2. Bob does not have Water
3. Carl does not have Apple
4. Carl does not have Rice

Is there a way to accomplish this?